# Selenium Webdriver - Issue with FirefoxDriver on Debian Lenny (Error No display)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to test my website, it opens up a URL using Firefox, logins and does some stuff on the page and then logs out and shuts firefox. That all works great on Windows 7. The code starts with:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(URL);
```

Now I deployed my jar in  linux box that runs Debian lenny which has iceweasel on it. A cron job starts the program which throws the following error when trying to open firefox:

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   Error: cannot open display: :0 Error: cannot open display: :0
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:106)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
>     at auth.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:15)   at
>   reader.ReaderThread.run(ReaderThread.java:67)
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary
>   FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows: 
>   Error: cannot open display: :0 Error: cannot open display: :0
>
> Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version:
>   '2.6.26-2-686', java.version: '1.6.0_26' Driver info: driver.version:
>   FirefoxDriver at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:110)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:190)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:179)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:92)
>     at auth.Authenticator.authenticate(Authenticator.java:15)   at
>   reader.ReaderThread.run(ReaderThread.java:67)

I have Xvfb running ok in the box and I have set variable DISPLAY to 0. I have searched around and none of the solutions (like setting the env variable) worked.

Isnt XVfb supposed to work as a non-graphical environment that the browser will launch into and do the necessary actions? What's stopping it from starting up?

I am using the latest Selenium version 2.31 and Firefox 3.0.6 Iceweasel.

**Edit:** Updated to Firefox 14 and still see the same issue. I even raised the timeout limit to 60 seconds.

driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

**SOLVED:** By running it with the xvfb wrapper, xvfb-run like this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=0 nohup java - jar X.jar
```

Comment: Are you able to launch firefox (or other X application) directly?

Comment: What version of Selenium & Firefox?

Comment: Have you considered using a hub/node setup? I've personally found that to be easier to work with.

Comment: I am using the latest Selenium version 2.31 and Firefox 3.0.6 Iceweasel.

Today I'll try to install a newer version of FF on my home dir and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-num=0 nohup java - jar X.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the similar issue and this is coming only for firefox, for other browser everything was working fine, I tried on Chrome.
Here is the solution for this
1. Check the version of FF, if it is latest, then go for a lesser version of FF. It is recommended for more stability.
2. And you should always try to take latest selenium binary from selenium website.
For more details try this solution:
http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/at-org-openqa-selenium-firefox-internal-newprofileextensionconnection-startnewprofileextensionconnection-java106/

Comment: This solution will not fix a problem with `DISPLAY`, which is the problem presented in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Either try to update your webdriver or downgrade your firefox.
this issue is related that selenium server cannot connect to your firefox.

Comment: Hi Buddy, what do you mean update my webdriver? I am using the latest version from Selenium for the WebDriver API so I think that's the one I should be using.

What version of Firefox do you recommend? I know that anything from the ones supported should do but if there's one that's repeatedly tested to work without issues that'd be ideal.

Comment: @WiQu: yes I can start firefox using xvfb-run firefox

Comment: Well AFAIR, I use the FF version either 14 or 18. Remember FF in Windows and Linux might be having different issue, to be safe always 1 or 2 Version below the released version of FF. My 2 cents.

Comment: The update didnt work, I used Firefox 14 and still get the same error.

Comment: hmm does it work if you try to connect it without using xvfb ?

Comment: otherwise change the xvfb port helps

Comment: Ok, weird thing

I connected to the box through the x2go client which spawns a desktop session. I ran the jar again and I saw Firefox opening up OK, doing the work it was supposed to and completing without issues.

This only happens when this is done without a desktop session, with the jar ran by the cron job.

Really confused..

Comment: well probably it is not selenium + ff issue, but another plugin for your linux, alternative you can always install jenkins to run all your test also with xvfb plugin :D

Comment: Hi buddy, really appreciate the help. What do you mean another forefox plugin? I am not really using any plugins for this, at least not that I know of.

How can I check what's affecting it? If I still can't find out I'll switch to Jenkins.

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't comment properly. Its cron job, I have no clue what is that. ... sorry. Jenkins is really good though for the scheduling too. Just download jenkins war, install xvfb plugins. then run your ant build from jenkins, you can even setup daily build or periodically build, as much as you want

Comment: Or if you still insist using cron jobs try to change xvfb display not using 0 but something else 10 or something

Comment: This solution will not fix a problem with `DISPLAY`, which is the problem presented in the question.

Answer (score -2):

This issue get resolved after upgraded to the latest Selenium jar.

Comment: This solution will not fix a problem with `DISPLAY`, which is the problem presented in the question.