# Processes not starting other processes when it's not me starting them?

Tags: python, unix, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, user-permissions

So I have this webpage. From this webpage, the user sets some stuff up, and presses a button, which makes an XMLHTTPRequest in Javascript to a php script on the server, passing a JSON string, which attempts to execute a python script after parsing the JSON and doing stuff to it:

execute_web_crawler.php:

```
$result = shell_exec("python /home/directories_go_here/web_crawl.py '".$json."' >> /home/some_other_directories_here/screenshots/test.txt");
fwrite($file, $result);
```

On this python script, it'll make some urllib magic happen, check some pages, and then once in a while, attempt to open a Firefox window using Selenium webdriver to verify something

web_crawl.py:

```
def confirm_ad_space(url):
    print "FINDING AD PLACEMENT ON ", url
    file_write.write("Finding placement...\n")
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    print "BROWSER ONLINE"
    file_write.write("Browser Initialized.\n")
```

file_writes are going to a log file that just has a lot of words about the script's execution, the command-line stuff done by the PHP would hopefully have those print statements outputting to TEST.txt.

But my output for the log stops at "Finding placement"

And the output for the TEST.txt on last execution was stopped in the middle of a print statement earlier in the code, like it got halfway through a word and stopped.

Now, when I run this python script manually from the CLI, it's fine. If I run it from the web interface, it goes to open a browser and stops. I'm assuming it might have something to do with permissions. IS there any way to ensure that the user that PHP is has access to Firefox or something?

Comment: Impossible to be sure without seeing the code, but it's most likely a permissions issue. If you're the owner of the script, you could try setting the setuid bit `chmod u+s` on the script, to see if that works.

Comment: Do you get any error messages from the Python script? Try `echo shell_exec('python /script.py 2>&1');` to see what's happening.

Comment: I'm not, I think it's just that CRON doesn't have the ability to launch firefox and do stuff with it, but my user is. I have no idea.

Comment: the PHP is being AJAX requested, too. I added a file_write to it, but it cut off in the middle of a python print statement. Like, it wrote half of a word. :\. My log file last displays what it says before it launches firefox.

Comment: How is `cron` involved? You don't mention that in your original question. If you're running a GUI app like `firefox` from outside the context of a login shell, you'll probably need to manually set the `DISPLAY` environment variable to an accessible X11 host.

Comment: Sorry, not cron, I meant PHP. I had other stuff running. Got a bit mixed up. I just rewrote the OP because why not. I'm gonna try to tweak it so it runs on just the PHP really quick to ensure I'm not somehow losing my mind.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really know anything about either Selenium or xvfb, and without being able to reproduce the fault, there's not much more I can suggest. There's a similar-ish question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877746/selenium-webdriver-issue-with-firefoxdriver-on-debian-lenny-error-no-display) which suggests you have to use `xvfb-run`.

Comment: Well, I'm just guessing it's a unix permission problem. Which is why I was tempted to avoid some details.

Comment: Also, just manually setting the php script's received variables got me

sh: cannot create /home/directories_here/TEST.txt: Permission denied